# Data Memory Barrier (DMB) in CMSIS libraries for Cortex-M3s

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, cortex-m

In the CMSIS definitions for gcc you can find something like this:

```
static __INLINE void __DMB(void) { __ASM volatile ("dmb"); }
```

My question is: what use does a memory barrier have if it does not declare "memory" in the clobber list?

Is it an error in the core_cm3.h or is there a reason why gcc should behave correctly without any additional help?

Comment: Good question. Note that Linux uses the `memory` clobber: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/system.h?v=2.6.39#L135

Comment: @ninjalj: Thanks for the link. (didn't come up on quick googling)

Comment: @ninjalj: I assume the correct link now is https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39/source/arch/arm/include/asm/system.h#L135

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some testing with gcc 4.5.2 (built with LTO). If I compile this code:

```
static inline void __DMB(void) { asm volatile ("dmb"); }
static inline void __DMB2(void) { asm volatile ("dmb" ::: "memory"); }

char x;

char test1 (void)
{
  x = 15;
  return x;
}

char test2 (void)
{
  x = 15;
  __DMB();
  return x;
}

char test3 (void)
{
  x = 15;
  __DMB2();
  return x;
}
```

using `arm-none-eabi-gcc -Os -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -c dmb.c`, then from `arm-none-eabi-objdump -d dmb.o` I get this:

```
00000000 <test1>:
   0:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <test1+0x8>)
   2:   200f        movs    r0, #15
   4:   7018        strb    r0, [r3, #0]
   6:   4770        bx  lr
   8:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

0000000c <test2>:
   c:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (18 <test2+0xc>)
   e:   200f        movs    r0, #15
  10:   7018        strb    r0, [r3, #0]
  12:   f3bf 8f5f   dmb sy
  16:   4770        bx  lr
  18:   00000000    .word   0x00000000

0000001c <test3>:
  1c:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (2c <test3+0x10>)
  1e:   220f        movs    r2, #15
  20:   701a        strb    r2, [r3, #0]
  22:   f3bf 8f5f   dmb sy
  26:   7818        ldrb    r0, [r3, #0]
  28:   4770        bx  lr
  2a:   bf00        nop
  2c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

It is obvious that `__DBM()` only inserts the `dmb` instruction and it takes `DMB2()` to actually force the compiler to flush the values cached in the registers.

I guess I found a CMSIS bug.

Comment: The DBM directive is defined by ARM, and the sample given at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHEBHFF.html would make no sense if a compiler could reorder non-qualified memory operations across it.

Comment: @supercat That's what I thought. It appears they did fix it in more recent releases: https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/9fe411cef1cef5de58e5957b89760759de44e393/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_gcc.h#L438

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the CMSIS version is right.

Injecting the barrier instruction without the memory in clobber list achieves exactly what it is supposed to do:

If the previous write on "x" variable was buffered then it is committed. This is useful, for example, if you are going to pass "x" address to as a DMA address, or if you are going to setup MPU.

It has no effect on returning "x" (your program is guaranteed to be correct even if you omit memory barrier).

On the other hand by inserting memory in clobber list, you have no kind of effect in situations like the example before (DMA, MPU..).

The only difference in the latter case is that if you have for example an ISR modifying the value of "x" right after "strb" , then the value that will be returned is the value modified by the ISR, because the clobber caused the compiler to read from memory to register again.
But if you want to obtain this thing then you should use "volatile" variables.

In other words: the barrier forces cache vs memory commit in order to guarantee consistency with other HW resources that might access RAM memory, while clobbering memory causes compiler to stop assuming the memory has not changed and to read again in local registers, that is another thing with different purposes (it does not matter if a memory change is still in cache or already committed on RAM, because an eventual asm load operation is guaranteed to work in both cases without barriers).

Comment: But isn't the compiler free to reorder the surrounding instructions so that the write to "x" does not hit the cache at all at the time the barrier is executed? I wanted the memory clobber so that the compiler is forced to commit the variable to (possibly cache) memory, and then the barrier to force the cache flush.

Comment: I'm curious in what situations `__DMB` would be useful in the absence of a compiler barrier?  The directive was defined by ARM, with the intention that code using it be portable among compilers that support it.  Their example of an intended usage in a spinlock mutex would be meaningless on a compiler that could reorder unqualified memory operations across it, since one of the major purposes of mutexes is typically to coordinate access to "ordinary" objects.